# Получение значений из формы

Tags: jsp, servlet, form, java

Всем доброго времени суток!
Вопрос такой:
Есть JSP-шка,которая содержит форму:несколько текстовых полей и одно поле для изображения.

1.
`<form method="post" action="StepTwo" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Когда из сервлета вытаскиваю значения через `request.getParameter` то почему-то всегда получаю `null`. 
А вот фотография вытаскивается как надо.
Листинг сервлета:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  
        String contentType = request.getContentType();
         response.setContentType("text/html;charset=Windows-1251");
       request.setCharacterEncoding("Cp1251");

         String email=(String) request.getParameter("email");
         out.print(email);
        String about=(String) request.getParameter("about");
        String day=(String)request.getParameter("day");
        String month=(String)request.getParameter("month");
        String year=request.getParameter("year");

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("email",email);
        session.setAttribute("about",about);
        session.setAttribute("birthday",year);

//------------------------------------
    String saveFile="";
 contentType = request.getContentType();
if((contentType != null)&&(contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)){
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
int formDataLength = request.getContentLength();
byte dataBytes[] = new byte[formDataLength];
int byteRead = 0;
int totalBytesRead = 0;
while(totalBytesRead < formDataLength){
byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead,formDataLength);
totalBytesRead += byteRead;
}
String file = new String(dataBytes);
saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);
saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1,saveFile.indexOf("\""));
int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("=");
String boundary = contentType.substring(lastIndex + 1,contentType.length());
int pos;
pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;
int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length;
int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length;
File ff = new File(saveFile);
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(ff);
fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));

fileOut.flush();
fileOut.close();
session.setAttribute("photo", dataBytes); 
//----------------------------------
}
  }
```

Ну,собственно, и вопрос! Почему не вытаскиваются другие значения и как их вытащить?

1.

```
form method="post" action="StepTwo" enctype="multipart/form-data;"
Email: input type="email" name="email" value="<% String email=(String)session.getAttribute("email");if (email!=null){out.print(email);}; %>" </br>
About You: input type="text" name="about" value="<% String about=(String)session.getAttribute("about");if (about!=null){out.print(about);}; %>"</br>
input type="file" name="foto"</br>
input type="submit" value="Шаг 3"
/form
```

2.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>StepTwo</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ServletStepAndSave.StepTwo</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>StepTwo</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/StepTwo</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

3.При выполнении сервлета отображается null ( out.print(email) )

Comment: много лишнего ненужного кода вы здесь оставили, мягко говоря он тут не предоставляет интереса. Лучше покажите код формы на jsp странице, маппинг сервлета в web.xml и вывод что у вас покажет   
    
    String email = request.getParameter("email"); // мне непонятно ваше приведение типов к стрингу метода который итак возвращает String
    System.out.println(email); // если выпадает тут NullPointerException  - будем разбираться, нет - значит проблемы в вашей логике и последующими действиями

Comment: Добавил необходимую информацию  в тело вопроса.

Comment: ну, пока далеко не убежал, пара советов - никогда не использовать java-code на jsp странице, для этого существуют jsp теги и теги jstl. Второе - никогда, никогда не называйте пакеты с большой буквы(я об этом уже упоминал). Если объект хранится в сессии - то тут и java-code не нужен, он виден и на странице. Как освобожусь - кину пример того как должно выглядеть. А пока, если есть время - читайте про jsp, его теги и jstl

Comment: Viacheslav, почему нельзя использовать названия пакетов с большой буквы? Какие есть сайд-эффекты этого? Я обычно всегда пишу с маленькой, а попал на проект, где с большой. В чем разница?(Лички увы не нашел на ХэшКоде)

Comment: System.out.println(email);

С чего бы здесь выпадать NullPointerException?
null передается в метод, а не метод вызывается у null.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вместо

```
String month=(String)request.getParameter("month");
```

вызывать

```
String month = request.getHeader("month");
```

или

```
String month = request.getAttribute("month");
```

Не могу сказать наверняка, но возможно, один из них.
Еще можно проверить по списку имен всех параметров, есть ли то, что вас интересует или нет (для атрибутов и заголовков аналогично):

```
Enumeration params = request.getParameterNames();
```

Comment: скорее всего 3 вариант должен подойти =)

Answer (score 1):

Все  оказалось немного сложнее. Проблема была в том, что если мы через форму передаем файл и текст, то из-за `enctype="multipart/form-data"` мы не может добраться через `request` до текстовых полей. Тогда на помощь приходит [FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/)

```
String email="";         
String about="";
String day="";
String month="";
String year="";
int count1=0,count2=0,count3=0,count4=0,count5=0;
boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
 if (!isMultipart) {
   } 
else { 
      FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
      ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
      List items = null;
      try {
          items = upload.parseRequest(request);
        } 
    catch (FileUploadException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
     Iterator itr = items.iterator();
     while (itr.hasNext()) 
       {
        FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();
        if (item.isFormField())
         {
          String name = item.getFieldName();
          String value = item.getString();
          if(name.equals("email"))
           {
              email=value;
           }
          if(name.equals("about"))
           {  
              about=value;                         
           }
          if(name.equals("day"))
           {  
             day=value;                         
           }
          if(name.equals("month"))
           {
              month=value;
           }
          if(name.equals("year"))
           {
              year=value;
           }

        }
       else
       {
         try {
              String itemName = item.getName();
              }
       }
   }
}
```

P.S. Всем большое спасибо за отзывы! Viacheslav, а правда,почему нельзя называть пакеты с большой буквы?

Comment: @Автостопом_до_Рая, хорошо что сами в этом разобрались, я думал ошибка в другом. Дело в том что существует так называем code convention in java, при соблюдении которого, разработчики, незнакомые друг с другом, могут проще понимать чужой код. На проекте может соблюдаться свой code convention, как в случае @Антон Феоктистов. Лично я, кода вижу запись ServletStepAndSave.StepTwo - думаю о вложенном классе, хоть и понимаю что это маловероятно в данном случае (может и возможно, надо проверить).

Answer (score 0):

Когда присваиваете значение, нужно писать не `<%...%>`, а `<%=...%>`.